# Is there a way to Abort an ETL Execution in C#?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have this example about how to execute ETL in C#

```
var app = new Application();
var pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);
var vars = pkg.Variables;
var pkgResults = pkg.Execute(null, vars, null, null, null);
if (pkgResults == DTSExecResult.Success)
    Console.WriteLine("Package ran successfully");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Package failed");
```

It works ok, but now I need more than result. I need to abort current execution, is there a way to do something like pgk.Abort()?

thanks...

Comment: What type is Application()?

Comment: @ChrisSchiffhauer I'm inferring this is related to SSIS, so the namespace would be [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.aspx)

Comment: In this case is: Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Package Class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.package.aspx), you can call `SuspendExecution()` like this:

```
pkg.SuspendExecution();
```